# Scale down SCNNode based on its SCNView size or phone screen size

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, arscnview

I have a big SCNNode and I want to scale it down. Currently node is scaled down based on a magic number. However the node should be scaled down based on the phone's screen size or node's SCNView size.

To make things easier I thought of having a certain padding for node's SCNView/phone screen.

So, given a SCNNode and a certain amount of padding within the phone screen/SCNView, I would like you to calculate the scale factor for the SCNNode.

See the attached image for visual explanation. Can you help me to calculate the scale factor?

[Visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0F8Y.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the screen scale factor with

```swift
UIScreen.main.nativeScale
```

or

```swift
UIScreen.main.scale
```